# Endless time-able loop

Tags: batch-file, timer

How do I create a batch file that runs all the time, but only performs what I want done at midnight? I know how to do the loop part.. or so I think, I've never done batch code programming before so I don't really know if its right.

```
:loop
Stuff
goto loop
```

But I need the `stuff` to run a python script everyday at midnight. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: This sounds like you're looking for the wrong method to solve the problem. Do you really want a batch file to constantly be running or do you want to schedule a script to run at midnight?

Comment: Well I want to schedule a script to run at midnight, but I don't want to use the Task Scheduler, and I don't know if batch files can be told to run at only certain times @glenatron

Comment: Why are you avoiding the Task Scheduler?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the Task Scheduler?

Comment: Because all of the machines where Im at don't have Task Scheduler...(Don't ask me how, but they dont lol) :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the system time showing 24 hour time.
The time format could be variable - you'd have to check what `echo %time%` shows when it's midnight.

```
@echo off
:loop
if "%time:~0,5%"==" 0:00" (
    echo launch python script.
    ping -n 60 localhost >nul
 )
ping -n 20 localhost >nul
goto :loop
```

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to see this, Thank you very much!

Comment: You might want to add the line   ping -n 60 localhost >nul   within the parenthesis after launching the python script so that you don't run the risk of launching it 3 times!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `at` command to schedule your batch job and leave alone dead cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You should try out **[Schtasks.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**, there is an example I wrote a while back on the [**Batch file** wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file), see ***:shutdown-clock***

or you could use the GUI version, which is [**Task Scheduler**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler)