# Batch script run with schedule in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a doStuff.bat script with this command : 
`"%HOME%\bin\groovy.bat" "%HOME%\bin\DoSth.groovy"`
What can i do to get that command run every 5 minute without using Window Task Schedule?

Comment: Why do you want to **not** use the scheduler?

Comment: helpful... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918294/endless-time-able-loop/16918426#16918426

Comment: I don't want use the scheduler because i want only a script with only one action (click to doStuff.bat file) to get the code in script run every 5 minute (with Windows Task Scheduler I have to do more actions - and this script is using for my customer who don't know how to use Window Task Scheduler ).And the code in script will be use in Linux with crontab

Comment: You can't run a Windows script in Linux.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake , i mean i will write a doStuff.sh similar as doStuff.bat and in doStuff.sh will be : `"/%HOME%/bin/groovy" "%HOME%/bin/DoSth.groovy"` and i want it run every 5 minute .Something like this in doStuff.sh : `"*/5 * * * *" "/%HOME%/bin/groovy.sh" "%HOME%/bin/DoSth.groovy"`

Comment: You mean your inexperienced users can add your script to `chrontab`, but they can not handle 5 mouse clicks to add it to the Windows Task Scheduler??

Comment: No no , i want user only run script doStuff.bat or doStuff.sh and the code in script `"/%HOME%/bin/groovy" "%HOME%/bin/DoSth.groovy"` will be run every 5 minutes

Answer (score 4):

The timeout command in modern windows will pause for 5 minutes/300 seconds.

```
@echo off
set "home=c:\home folder"
:loop
call "%HOME%\bin\groovy.bat" "%HOME%\bin\DoSth.groovy"
timeout 300
goto :loop
```

Comment: Thanks ,but it not work for me ,i've tested with 30 second and it only run one time

Comment: I added the `call` keyword which is normally needed when running batch files.  Try it now.